Finding out when someone voted for your question on Stack Exchange
Here is a question I posted on a Stack Exchange website: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404052/why-is-the-traveling-salesperson-problem-difficult
Is it possible to see a complete history of when (timestamp) each upvote and downvote occurred?
For example:
  score           timestamp cumulative_score
    10 2024-07-31 17:21:33               10
   -10 2024-08-01 02:55:01                0
   -10 2024-08-01 05:11:04              -10
   -10 2024-08-01 06:28:40              -20
    10 2024-08-01 07:15:45              -10
   -10 2024-08-01 13:21:15              -20

Can this be done with the Stack Overflow API?
The closest thing I found was this: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4404052/timeline

But this does not contain the full voting history. I do not need to know which users voted - just the times at which the score changed.
References:

Can you see the voting history of a question / answer

Note: The reason I am asking - I am interested in knowing if the intensity at which scores change on a question can be modelled using a random walk (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)

You linked to a version of the timeline where you had hidden the vote summaries. Click the "Show vote summaries" button at the top to get to https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4404052/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

For future reference, questions about using the API are on-topic for the main site. As the answers clearly show, they are of a coding nature and should not be migrated. Once migrated, there is no option to migrate it back. This question should not have been migrated, but there is no easy path to fix that now.


Is it possible to see a complete history of when (timestamp) each upvote and downvote occurred?

No, that is not possible, for security/privacy reasons. The best you get is a vote tally on a date. That goes for the API /question/timeline endpoint


const ApiUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/questions/4404052/timeline?site=math&filter=!bbZvl7Y9jHviql'

const providers = {
   'creation_date': getDateTime
}

function getValue(v) {
  return v;
}

function getFieldNames(items) {
     const hdrs = items.reduce( (a, c) => { 
      for(const f in c) {
          a[f] = providers[f] ?? getValue
      }
      return a
   }, {})
   return hdrs;
}

function addHeaders(hdrs) {
     const head = document.getElementById('head')
     const tr = document.createElement('tr')
     for(const h in hdrs) {
        const th = document.createElement('th')
        th.textContent = h
        tr.appendChild(th)
     }
     head.appendChild(tr)
     return hdrs
}

function zero(v) {
  return v<10?`0${v}`:v.toString()
}

function getDate(dt) {
  return `${dt.getUTCFullYear()}-${zero(dt.getUTCMonth()+1)}-${zero(dt.getUTCDay())}`
}

function getTime(dt) {
  return `${zero(dt.getUTCHours())}:${zero(dt.getUTCMinutes())}:${zero(dt.getUTCSeconds())}`
}

function getDateTime(v) {
  const d = new Date(v * 1000)
  return `${getDate(d)} ${getTime(d)} `
}

function addRowForItem(item, hdrs) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
  for(const f in hdrs) {
     const td = document.createElement('td')
     td.textContent = hdrs[f](item[f])
     tr.appendChild(td)
  }
  return tr
}

function addRows(items, tbody) {
   const hdrs = addHeaders(getFieldNames(items))
   items
     .map(i => addRowForItem(i,hdrs))
     .forEach(i => tbody.appendChild(i))
}

function addError(err) {
  addRows([err], document.getElementById('list'))
}

fetch(ApiUrl)
  .then( r => r.json())
  .then( j => j.items ?? [j])
  .then( items => addRows(items, document.getElementById('list')))
  .catch( e => addError(e))
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

th, td {
  text-align:right;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 3px;
}
<table>
<thead id='head'>
</thead>
<tbody id='list'>
</tbody>
</table>



as well as for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer or data dump for that matter:
select *
from votes
where postid=4404052
and votetypeid in (1,2,3) -- accept, up, down

By having timestamps with seconds precision would make it too easy to link activity of users to their voting. For the record: not even moderators have access to these timestamps. Even for them voting is anonymous.

@ rene: thank you so much for your answer! Do you know if its possible to run this code in R or Python?

@stats_noob Python is possible for sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+stackexchange-api  and that seems to go for R as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+stackexchange-api. If you have trouble adapting those existing answers to your specific needs, ask a new question with your attempt to adapt and implement my javascript in R or Python.

Yes, it's definitely possible to obtain the timestamps, down to the second, of upvotes and downvotes on a non-deleted post from the SE API. That timestamp data is also publicly available through the stock website user interface. Voting timestamps are available in the post author's reputation history. It is not convenient, in that you have to filter it out of all reputation changes for the author, but it is available. From the SE API, that data is even available for meta sites.
For the SE API, the endpoint you can use is /users/{ids}/reputation-history. Given that question is your own, you also have the option to use the /users/{id}/reputation-history/full endpoint, which requires authentication to get your own private reputation changes, but the data for upvotes and downvotes received is public, so using that endpoint isn't required.
Simplified example using this current meta question
For example, you can find the timestamps of the, currently, two upvotes and two downvotes on the question this answer is posted on from https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/23512643/reputation-history?site=meta.stackoverflow
This shows that the votes were:



vote
epoch timestamp to seconds
UTC timestamp




post_downvoted
1724998903
2024-08-30 06:21:43


asker_accepts_answer
1725047380
2024-08-30 19:49:40


post_upvoted
1725134432
2024-08-31 20:00:32


post_downvoted
1726983829
2024-09-22 05:43:49


post_downvoted
1726989788
2024-09-22 07:23:08



Getting the vote timestamps for the specific question you asked about on Math.SE
From the SE API
You will need to filter through the data from multiple pages of responses from https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/1296713/reputation-history?pagesize=100&site=math for post_id = 4404052. Given that we know the creation date of the post, 2022-03-15, we can find the earliest page on which we will need to look for votes on that question. Currently, using page_size=100, that's page 14 and starts with a post_upvoted event at 1647365009, which is 2022-03-15 17:23:29 UTC.
Publicly available on the site in the author's reputation history
The timestamp data for upvotes and downvotes are also available publicly in your reputation history pages on all SE site, including the Mathematics site, excluding per-site meta sites, as those don't show separate reputation, but such reputation is tracked by the system, as the above simplified example shows. The timestamps for voting events are easily seen in the reputation history's "Posts" view. Again using the question's creation date, 2022-03-15, we can find that votes for the question you're using as an example here, currently start on page 15 of your reputation history, which, with the events for that question expanded, looks like (timestamps are shown to the minute; timestamps to the second are in tooltips for each event timestamp):

